# How can I draw this image in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I´d like to use the image below in a text that I am writing for a paper. This image is from a chapter of a and I'm afraid to use it due to copyright. I am clearly quoting the book in my paper, but the image I would like to make using Latex.
I've done everything. I've read tutorials on latex tikz. I already tried to make this image in Geogebra and export the tikz Latex code. But I didn't even come close.
Could someone help me do it?

[image]

In this image I´d like to change $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I´d like to get words out "Discrete support:" and take only $E = \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I got it. Thanks too much for your comment.